# Use realloc() after malloc() to change the size of unsigned char array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

In the main function, I use malloc() to create an unsigned char array:

```
int main()
{
  int length = 64;
  unsigned char *array = (unsigned char *)malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned char));
  ...
  change_size(array, length);
}
```

change_size() defined in .h:

```
void change_size(unsigned char* arr, int len);
```

In the change_size function, I will use realloc() to increase the array size:

```
void change size(unsigned char* arr, int len)
{
  printf("%d\n", len);
  len = len + 16;
  printf("%d\n", len);
  arr = (unsigned char *)realloc(arr, len * sizeof(unsigned char));
  int new_len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  printf("%d\n", new_len);  
}
```

The printf() show me:

```
64
80
8
```

The array size in the main() also needs to be updated.

Then how to change this array size correctly?

Comment: Note that `realloc` could return `NULL` while leaving the original pointer intact if it fails.

Comment: What is `ciphertext` and how was it created?

Comment: @ToninGuy3n: I changed ciphertext to arr, typo

Comment: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);` is only a valid way to calculate the number of elements for _actual_ arrays.  Since `arr` is a pointer, not an array, `sizeof(arr)` is the size of a pointer.

Comment: By the way, this feels more like C code than C++ code, but I might be being picky.

Comment: Anyway, unless I'm misunderstanding, `void change_size(array, length);` seems misplaced in `main()`. Specifically, the `void` keyword feels like it doesn't belong here for some reason.

Comment: @Chipster: yes, i copy c code in cpp project to run.

Comment: @LiDong Did it run properly under C?

Comment: @Chipster: yes. i change tag back to c

Comment: @LiDong If it ran under C, but not C++, then it is probably actually a C++ question. Then you were actually right, and I was wrong. By the way, you may want to edit your question add this information to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your parameters as pointers if you want to change their value back in the caller.  That also means you pass your array pointer as a pointer, because `realloc` might change it:

```
int change_size(unsigned char **arr, int *len)
{
    int new_len = *len + 16;
    unsigned char *new_arr = realloc(*arr, new_len);
    if (new_arr) {
        *len = new_len;
        *arr = new_arr;
    }
    return new_arr != NULL;
}
```

Here I've modified `change_size` to suit, and also added a return value to indicate success, since `realloc` can fail to resize the memory.  For clarity, I removed the `printf` calls.  Oh, and I also removed the cast, since that is not valid in C.

Example usage:

```
if (!change_size(&array, &len))
{
    perror("change_size failed");
}
```

One final note is that you can use your `change_size` function for the first allocation too, rather than calling `malloc`.  If the first argument to `realloc` is NULL, it does the same thing as `malloc`.

Comment: how should i declare len and arr in main()?

Comment: Exactly how they are already.  I made a typo in the example usage.  It should have been `length` to match the name you're using in `main`.

Comment: oh,i see my issue, in main, i should call change_size(&array, len). if i also change to declare int *length, i should call change_size(&array, &len), is it?

Comment: No.  You asked me how to define these values.  I said _"exactly the same"_, and you seem to have interpreted that as _"different'_.  I meant that there is _no change_ to how you have currently defined them in `main`.  You use `&` to acquire a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

First C is not babysitter language,
You only need basic things then you can do everything,
Just try hard to totally understand basic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(){
    int G1_Len=20;
    int G2_Len=40;
    char* G1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*G1_Len);
    char* G2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*G2_Len);
    printf("This is G1's Size:%d,Becuz G1 is Pointer\n",sizeof(G1));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(G2));

    printf("This is what you need just add a variable remainber your size\n%d\n",G1_Len);
    printf("%d\n",G2_Len);
    /*alloc and free is a pair of memory control you need,remember least function thinking more is tip of C*/
    /*if you need alot of function but you cant control all try c++*/
    /*and if in c++ using new and delete dont use malloc free*/
    free(G1);
    free(G2);
    G1=NULL;
    G2=NULL;



    G1_Len=22;
    G1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*G1_Len);
    //Now you have 22 bytes of char array




    free(G1);



    return 0;
}
```

Okay I answer it.    @Chipster

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int change_size(char** arr, int len)
{
    char* nar=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+16));
    if(nar){
        free(* arr);
        *arr=nar;
        nar[10]='K';//this will let you know its right
        return len+16;
    }
    return len;
}

int main(){
    int G1_Len=20;
    int G2_Len=40;
    char* G1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*G1_Len);
    char* G2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*G2_Len);
    printf("This is G1's Size:%d,Becuz G1 is Pointer\n",sizeof(G1));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(G2));

    printf("This is what you need just add a variable remainber your size\n%d\n",G1_Len);
    printf("%d\n",G2_Len);
    /*alloc and free is a pair of memory control you need,remember least function thinking more is tip of C*/
    /*if you need alot of function but you cant control all try c++*/
    /*and if in c++ using new and delete dont use malloc free*/
    free(G1);
    free(G2);
    G1=NULL;
    G2=NULL;



    G1_Len=22;
    G1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*G1_Len);
    //Now you have 22 bytes of char array


    printf("%d\n",G1);
    G1_Len=change_size(&G1,G1_Len);
    printf("%c\n",G1[10]);
    printf("%d\n",G1);
    printf("%d\n",G1_Len);
    free(G1);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I mean yes, C++ doesn't hold your hand, but you might not want to put it that way in an answer. Also, good answers try to explain why something works or happens. Try to incorporate this in your answers.

Comment: This answer does not attempt to address any of the points in the original question.  Instead it seems to go on some weird tangent, offering advice as comments buried in a block of code that is not even related to the original code.